# Laravel : Getting Single value from the database using pluck

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

Hi everyone I'm using Laravel and I'm trying to get a single value from the database using `pluck`,
the issue is the query must be written in the Laravel way not the normal sql.so how to write this
sql query in Laravel ? I want to be able use `AS` to change the column name and `SUM`.all I want actually is to get the value from `total_quantity` column to do that I have to use pluck.
any idea how to write that query ?

Thanks in advance.

```
$PhysicalStock=DB::select("select sum(quantity) as `total_quantity` from InOutProducts where productID=$productID and InAndOut=1;")->pluck('total_quantity');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read more about Larvel DB and Eloquent.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

```
DB::table('InOutProducts')->selectRaw('SUM(quantity) as total_quantity')->where('productId', '=', $productID)->where('InAndOut', '=', 1)->pluck('total_quantity');
```

Comment: Will your query somehow is helpful it's like 95% accurate but the the pluck not picking any value  ? because no value in $PhysicalStock.

Comment: Don't understand what are you said. Please give more information what you need

Comment: The Physicalstock variable is empty(no value) thats what I mean $phyiscalStock=DB::table('InOutProducts')->selectRaw('SUM(quantity) as total_quantity')->where('productId', '=', $productID)->where('InAndOut', '=', 1)->pluck('total_quantity');

Comment: khm... and and data in your DB is present?

Comment: when I run the query I can see in the error log in laravel the $PhysicalStock variable has no value to give ? I believe that because `SUM(quantity) as total_quantity` total_quantity is not real column so that's why pluck not putting any variable into $physicalStock.

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lastUpdateBy='osacapcom' where productID=1' at line 1 (SQL: update productsStock set physicalStock=,lastUpdateBy='osacapcom' where productID=1;)

Comment: Looks like, you run some update query. But we are talking about select query

Comment: the update query fail because the select statement didn't put a value into the $physicalStock variable ,I manage to solve the issue but not in the Laravel way you can say in the manual way below is my solution

Comment: $row=DB::select("select sum(quantity) as total_quantity from InOutProducts  where productID='$productID' and InAndOut='1'");
$PhysicalStock=$row[0]->total_quantity;